# Collapse duplicate row values and pivot wider non duplicate rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to combine rows where the column values are the same (ID:Var2) and where they're different (Var3:Var4) I would like to spread to unique columns based on the Var5 variable.

My data looks as follows:

```
 foo <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2),Var1 = c("A","A","C","C"),Var2 = c("B","B","D","D"),Var3 = c("X","Y","Z",NA),var4 = c("S","T","U","V"),Var5 = c("RF","SJ","RF","SJ"))
```

I would like my data to look as follows:

```
bar <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2),Var1 = c("A","C"), Var2 = c("B","D"), RF_Var3 = c("X","Z"), RF_Var4 = c("S","U"), SJ_var3 = c("Y","NA"),SJ_Var4 = c("T","V"))
```

It's important that the SJ vars are ordered together and similarly the RF vars.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` option

```
foo %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Var3:var4) %>%
  arrange(ID, Var1, Var2, Var5) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID:Var2, values_from = value, names_from = Var5:name)
```

which gives

```
     ID Var1  Var2  RF_Var3 RF_var4 SJ_Var3 SJ_var4
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1     1 A     B     X       S       Y       T
2     2 C     D     Z       U       <NA>    V
```

---

Similarly, a `data.table` option with `dcase` might help as well

```
dcast(
  melt(setDT(foo), id = c("ID", "Var1", "Var2", "Var5"))[order(ID, Var1, Var2, Var5)],
  ID + Var1 + Var2 ~ Var5 + variable,
  value = c("value")
)
```

which gives

```
   ID Var1 Var2 RF_Var3 RF_var4 SJ_Var3 SJ_var4
1:  1    A    B       X       S       Y       T
2:  2    C    D       Z       U    <NA>       V
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# note that Var4 is capital letter V, which is slightly different from your sample data
foo %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID:Var2), values_from = Var3:Var4, names_from = Var5, names_glue = "{Var5}_{.value}")

# A tibble: 2 x 7
     ID Var1  Var2  RF_Var3 SJ_Var3 RF_Var4 SJ_Var4
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 A     B     X       Y       S       T      
2     2 C     D     Z       NA      U       V
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a many step Base R way I'm sure could be simplified using `reshape()`:

```
# Subset of the unique values we would like to view the transposed data
# by: dimensions => data.frame
dimensions <- unique(foo[,1:3])

# Name of vector thats values we are to transpose: transpose_vec => character scalar
transpose_vec <- "Var5" 
 
# Names of vectors thats values are to be spread by the transposition: 
# vecs_to_spread => character vector
vecs_to_spread <- setdiff(names(foo), c(names(dimensions), transpose_vec))

# Foreach value of the transpose vec, repeat it by the number of vectors 
# we are going to spread it:  tpd_foo_vecs => character vector
tpd_foo_vecs <- unique(paste(rep(foo[,transpose_vec], each = length(vecs_to_spread)), 
                             vecs_to_spread, sep = "_"))

# Transpose the vectors to spread and flatten the values out into a vector: 
# vals => character vector
vals <- c(t(foo[,vecs_to_spread]))

# Name the values using the transposed vector: named_vals => named character vector
named_vals <- setNames(vals, rep(tpd_foo_vecs, length(vals)/length(tpd_foo_vecs)))

# Split the vector into a list, flatten into a data.frame and column bind 
# with the dimensions: res => data.frame
res <- cbind(dimensions, data.frame(split(named_vals, names(named_vals))))
```